# What is the meaning of "foo(...arg)" (three dots in a function call)?

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell what is "..." in the below code in the "Intro to Angular" example?

```
getHeroes() {
    this.backend.getAll(Hero).then( (heroes: Hero[]) => {
      this.logger.log(`Fetched ${heroes.length} heroes.`);
      this.heroes.push(...heroes); // fill cache
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery or Angular. It's a feature that was introduced in ES2015.

This particular use of `...` [doesn't actually have an official name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196). A name that is in line with other uses would be "spread argument" (a generic term would be ["spread syntax"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)). It "explodes" (spreads) an *iterable* and passes each value as argument to the function. Your example is equivalent to:

```
this.heroes.push.apply(this.heroes, Array.from(heroes));
```

Besides being more concise, another advantage of `...` here is that it can be more easily used with other concrete arguments:

```
func(first, second, ...theRest);

// as opposed to the following or something similar:
 func.apply(null, [first, second].concat(Array.from(heroes)));
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a JavaScript feature called  **Rest Parameters.**
By using it your function can take any number of arguments. 
You put the three dots just before the argument (without a whitespace character) and the mechanism spreads it for you as if it was a list of several arguments.
In Eloquent Javascript you have a good example of it.

```
let numbers = [5, 1, 7];
console.log(max(...numbers));
// -> 7
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a copy of the original array

```
let args = [7, 3, 8];
var [h] = args.reverse(); // args is now 8, 3, 7
```

whereas

```
var [h] = [...args].reverse(); // args is still 7, 3, 8
```

It can also be used to specify the remaining values of an array

```
var [first, ...rest] = args; // first = 7, rest = [3, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the title of the question, the use of **...** in a function declaration (within parenthesis) is that of a **rest operator** or **rest parameter**,In order to help us create more flexible functions, ES6 introduces the rest parameter for function parameters.

With the rest parameter, you can create functions that take a *variable number of arguments*. These arguments are stored in an **array** that can be accessed later from inside the function.

Example: 1

```
function foo(...args) {
  return "You have passed " + args.length + " arguments.";
}

console.log(foo(0, 1, 2,4)); // You have passed 4 arguments.
console.log(foo("hello", null, [1, 2], { })); // You have passed 4 arguments.
```

Example 2:

```
function foo(...args){
     args.forEach(function(arg){
        console.log(arg);
     })
   }

   foo(2,3,4,5,6);
```

The rest parameter eliminates the need to check the args array and allows us to apply map(), filter(), reduce() and other array Higher Order functions on the parameters array.

**OTHER USE CASES OF ... operator :**

1. Used as **spread operator** which is the reverse of **rest operator**.

   `const arr = [6, 89, 3, 45];
   const maximum= Math.max(...arr);
   console.log(maximum);`
2. **...** operator is used to copy the array or an object pretty easily and is quite helpful in javascript frameworks and libraries like angular and react respectively.

   ```
   const arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
   const arr2 = [...arr1];
   console.log(arr2);//  [1,2,3,4];

   const obj1 = {
     name:'john',
     age:25
   }

   const obj2 = {...obj1};
   console.log(obj2); // Now obj2 is new object and is copy of obj1 (non-mutated 
   way)
   ```