# What is the [i] doing in this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, arguments

```
const removeFromArray = function(firstArray,...toRemove) {
    let modifiedArray = [...firstArray];
    for (let i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
        if (modifiedArray.includes(toRemove[i])) {
            modifiedArray.splice(modifiedArray.indexOf(toRemove[i]), 1)
        }    
    }
    return modifiedArray;
};
console.log(removeFromArray([3,4,5], 3,5)) ; //result is [4]
```

Goal : to take any array as first argument and remove whatever you want from said array as next argument.

Sorry this is keeping me from sleeping but what is `[i]` doing attached `toRemove`?

Lets say I want to do `removeFromArray(['a','b','c'], 'b');`

This will mean `toRemove` is equal to 'b'. The length of toRemove will be 1. So the loop says run for one iteration because toRemove is only 1 length.

To this point I think I understand. I don't get why `(modifiedArray.includes(toRemove[i]))` because doesn't that just mean `(modifiedArray.includes('b'[1]))` ?

And if you do a like `removeFromArray(['a','b','c'], 'a', 'c');` Would the `[i]` mean that `toRemove` will get iterated twice, once for each, so for the second iteration its value would be 2?

```
(modifiedArray.includes(['a', 'c'][1]))
(modifiedArray.includes(['a' ,'c'][2]))
```

or would it be

```
(modifiedArray.includes(['a' ,'c'][1]))
(modifiedArray.includes(['a' ,'c'][1]))
```

I hope I was able to kind of explain my confusion I'm a bit frustrated. Thanks!

Comment: _"This will mean toRemove is equal to 'b'."_ - No, it would be `[ 'b' ]` (or `[ 'a', 'c' ]` for your second example), because that's what the `...` does -> [Rest parameters - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "...args" (three dots) in a function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184674/what-is-the-meaning-of-args-three-dots-in-a-function-definition)

Comment: Okay that makes more sense but still, the [i]?

Comment: How else would you access the elements of an array in a `for`loop?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm the one asking the questions here, mate. <3. So with my newfound knowledge I understand that we made toRemove an array let's stick with [ 'a', 'c' ]. Still a simpler concept to grasp. The purpose of the [i] is my actual question. Why its there what its doing yata yata, what changes without it....

Comment: I think you mistake @Andreas' question for an actual question, rather than something to help you learn.

Comment: No I don't mistake it. I get I can fish around for 'accessing elements of an array' but if he knows the answer why not just say it. I'm burnt out and thought that response would get me the quickest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const removeFromArray = function (firstArray, ...toRemove) {`

Read about [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) first.

`firstArray` will be first argument you are passing to this function.

`...toRemove` takes rest of the argument as an Array.

If you call the function this way `removeFromArray([1,3,4], 4,5,6,7)`,

`firstArray` will be equal to `[1, 3, 4]`

`toRemove` will be equal to `[4, 5, 6, 7]`

`let modifiedArray = [...firstArray];` // this will create a copy of the `firstArray` and store it in `modifiedArray`.

`for (let i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {`

This will loop over the `toRemove` array whose value is [4, 5, 6, 7]

`if (modifiedArray.includes(toRemove[i])) {`

In the first iteration, it will check `toRemove[0]` which is `4` exists in `modifiedArray`, if it exists it will remove that element from the `modifiedArray` in the next line.
In the second iteration it will check `toRemove[1]` which is `5` and remove it from `modifiedArray` likewise it will go on removing all the elements present in `toRemove` from `modifiedArray`.

`modifiedArray.splice(modifiedArray.indexOf(toRemove[i]), 1);`

At the end it will remove all the elements which the array `toRemove` contains from the `modifiedArray` which is a copy of `firstArray` and return it.

Comment: You're a saint thank you. I had gotten so locked into thinking about it one way but I see now what is happening and will sleep much happier.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because of the  [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

From MDN Documentation

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number
> of arguments as an array.

so in your example your arguments passed to your `removeFromArray`function `(3,5)` become an array named `toRemove` and in order to access the values you would have to do remove[i].

here is an example to help you clarify

```js
const removeFromArray = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
}
removeFromArray(1, 3)
```

adding the `spread operator` and passing the values as a single `argument`

```js
 const removeFromArray = function(...toRemove){
  console.log(toRemove)
}
  removeFromArray(1,3)
```

Comment: I much better understand rest parameters now, but why can't their values be accessed in a for loop without the [i] attached?

Comment: because that's the only way to access values from an array, how would you access the values in array?

Comment: You can also use `for ..of` loop to iterate over an array.

Comment: @slooo7 in OP's example there is already a for loop

Comment: I plan to read about for..of tomorrow thank you. This is not my code so I don't really understand why I need the [i] if in my original code the rest parameter makes it an array then why can't I reference that array without [i] and what value does [i] have when the function runs? I get its necessary or the only way but I don't get why...

Comment: @James Ross because to access the `values` of an array in a `loop` you have to iterate through the `array `and proving an `index` to each element in this case the index is ` i`  and inside the loop each time `i` value changes starting from 0 all the way to the length of the array-1

Comment: @JamesRoss here is a link to learn more about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: _"...and what value does [i] have when the function runs?"_ - If you don't know how a `for` loop works then you really should have a look at its documentation (e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)) or grab a tutorial on how to work with arrays

Comment: @JamesRoss I highly recommend you taking @Andreas's advise on board and find a good tutorial about ` arrays`, `objects` , `for of loop`

Comment: thanks fellas I was being stupid but it all came back to me after solooo broke it down. I wasn't processing that toRemove was an array and [i] was accessing value via looping by length. I feel like a monkey who tied a knot but oh well.

Comment: I will look into as much as I can its hard because I'm trying to teach myself but keep ending up with real life pulling me away and then forgetting stuff like how to access values in arrays cause I haven't done it in a month. Its frustrating. Thanks again I'll read up.

Comment: @James Ross Just keep practicing you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

`toRemove.length`determines the number of cycles，Each value in `toremove` is executed once.

There's another important thing，`indexOf` only shows `index` of the first lookup object. So, if there are more than one same number in the array, it will not be deleted.

```
['a','b','b'].indexOf('b')
```

I'm not good at English. I can only talk to you so much.