# Why do I get wrong string format for javascript Set

Tags: javascript

I want to get `test2` as String but I got only "1" instead of "1, 2, 3".

```js
let test = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(String(test));

let test2 = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(String(...test2));
```

Comment: Why do you expect the [`String` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String) to understand multiple arguments (`String(1, 2, 3)`)?

Comment: [What is the meaning of "...args" (three dots) in a function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184674/what-is-the-meaning-of-args-three-dots-in-a-function-definition)

Comment: @Andreas why not since she understands array

Comment: An array is one element. `String()` can handle one element (as long as it can be converted into a string). `...array` is not one element...

Answer (score 1):

`String()` converts an array to a string.

You were not converting Set into an array correctly, you just needed square brackets with the spread operator.

```js
let test2 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 3]);
console.log(String([...test2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

`String(...test2)` spreads out the elements from the set into discrete arguments to `String`. With your example set, it's the same as doing `String(1, 2, 3)`. The [`String` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String) doesn't do anything with any arguments you pass it other than the first one, so `String(1, 2, 3)` gives you the same result as `String(1)`: It converts the argument to string, returning `"1"`.

If you want to get, say, `"1, 2, 3"`, you could spread the contents of the set into an array and use `join`:

```js
let test2 = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(
    [...test2].join(", ")
);
```